# Splitting a string of numbers following a pattern/sequence

Tags: python, mysql, list, split

I have a long text file that needs to be splitted up.
Every line has 178 characters consisting of numbers and characters.
I would like to split them up following a pattern as they need to be put in a mysql database.
It needs to be something like this:

First number to 10th number = key

11th number to 15th number = ID

16th number to 25th = NAME

23th to 26th = Ref nr.

And so on. So the way it needs to be splitted is unusual but I know on what index it needs to be splitted.

Any ideas?

Thnx by advance

Comment: Please post what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
file_data = [i.strip('\n') for i in open('filename.txt')]

new_data = [[i[:10], i[11:15], i[16:25], i[23:26]] for i in file_data]
```

This will now create a list of lists containing the key, ID, name, and ref nr.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353940/why-would-a-question-thats-normally-too-broad-in-any-other-language-be-okay-i/353947#353947